# Group by range of DATETIME - MySql

Tags: mysql, database

Well, I have a table with some columns that some of these are repeated, but the time is not exactly the same, I need to do a group by that has a range of 2 hours.

Notice that all the fields marked in black repeat, but the datetime field may differ by a few minutes, so I need to make a group by joining everyone within that two-hour interval.

[image]

It would be something like: `SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo, data`  **AND horaIfull_oco range 2h**

And also in the result it is necessary that the columns come with all their ids **if possible**, eg: `id1, id2` etc etc

He would join all those who had a maximum of two hours apart.
I have already researched and found nothing, if anyone knows how to do.

Comment: Lets say there are two time values: `02:01:00` and `04:00:00`. Different between them is less than two hours. So both will be grouped together; or they will be under the `02:00:00` and `04:00:00` groups respectively ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya will be grouped in a single result, no matter which of them appears, I just need them to be grouped and if possible, in return come the id of each one, example if grouped 2 records, have there: id1, id2 ...

Comment: you mean for example, all values satisfying "value >= 14:00:00 and value < 16:00:00" will be in group "14", all values satisfying "value >= 16:00:00 and value < 18:00:00" will be in group "16", etc.?

Comment: @mangusta This, an interval of 2 hours up and down

Comment: @WotonSampaio Your two responses above are contradictory, if you are struggling to explain in English.. explain in data! Provide sample data and a desired response for a range of rows with times within 2 hours and not of each other. I can see 3 possible interpretations of your question; groups start at arbitrary times 2 hrs apart (2,4,6,8); groups start at the earliest (previously ungrouped) time and extend for 2 hours; or all chains of rows within 2 hours of each other form one group (rows at 1,2,3,4,5,6, 9,10,11,12 form two groups (1,2,3,4,5,6) and (9,10,11,12)).

Comment: It is not specified in your question the start time or end time of the range. I mean 2 hours starting or ending when? The day has 24hours. Do a group by on other fields and use `WHERE horaIfull_oco BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 HOUR) AND NOW()` if you wanted the last two hours from now.

Comment: @PeterDarmis So, I want to list all the records that form that group with which they have 2 hours up or down of themselves, so in the image the 2 fields there would unite, you understand? I do not want specific records, I want the whole listing but with a grouping between them when the datetime of the field `hourIfull_oco` satisfy: **2h down < ((another record) hourIfull_oco) >= hourIfull_oco >= ((another record) hourIfull_oco) < 2h up**

Comment: @WotonSampaio perhaps a `GROUP BY HOUR(horaIfull_oco)` be enough? Although as i understand you have 12 2-hour periods in a day so every listing in the database for that day would have to belong in one of those 12 2-hour periods. A query like that would definitely need `IF` statement or `CASE .. WHEN`.

Comment: @WotonSampaio continuing from last comment i think you need a `CASE .. WHEN` statement used in your `GROUP BY`. I will post an example answer later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can select `floor(hour / 2)` which will tell you which two hour period it belongs in and group by that along with the date:

```
SELECT *,
    group_concat(id_oco) as grouped_ids,
    floor(HOUR(horaIfull_oco) / 2) AS two_hour
FROM tabela
GROUP BY inclusao_oco, sinistro, prefixo, data, DATE(horaIfull_oco), two_hour
```

Comment: Check this comment and corresponding explanation by OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348367/group-by-range-time-mysql?noredirect=1#comment93575147_53348367

Comment: This worked fine, but would it be possible in the result, to show the Ids of the grouped records?

Comment: Hey Madhur - I understand there is a certain amount of ambiguity here, but if you are grouping by a two hour period you really have no choice but to define the period somehow.  Where OP draws the line is up to them but the mechanics of this query still stand

Comment: @WotonSampaio - sure - see revised query in the answer

Comment: Dude, you saved my freelancer, thank you, it worked perfectly here.

Comment: @billynoah That was the purpose of asking a clear question to OP. OP contradicted it by giving weird logic, and now accepted an answer which works the other way around. OP himself is unclear about the subject. I know your answer works, and is the sane way to approach this problem. +1

Comment: Note that `SELECT *` under a `GROUP BY` clause is not recommended, this can generate conflicts with engines that have the option [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: @WotonSampaio keep in mind that using `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function, [MySQL can pick any value within the grouped records](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). For example `id_oco` may be `1` on one query, and `5` on another, unless you explicitly state `MAX(id_oco)`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Hehe I think I did not understand very well what you approached, my English is not a strong one, so the question or my comment may have seemed a little out of context kkkkkk

Comment: @fyrye Since there in the end shows all ids groups, this will not matter much

Comment: @WotonSampaio It will matter. Just try running the code in other RDBMS, or the latest versions of MySQL (5.7 and above); it will fail. The current answers utilizes a (mis)feature of older versions of MySQL, which were lenient.

Comment: @WotonSampaio if the only desired value is from the `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT FROM` that would qualify as your aggregate function. However in your question, you did not specify an end result of the data to be retrieved and stated `SELECT *`, so it appears that you were/are looking for every column from that grouping without an aggregate. Which can and will retrieve random records from those columns. Also keep in mind `GROUP_CONCAT` has a character limit of 1024 by default.

Comment: @WotonSampaio - The points being made here about this select are valid.  You will be ok as long as you (a) understand that the value returned on any non-aggregated column will be arbitrary and (b) are ok with that know how to turn off full group by mode. I've been in situations where it's actually beneficial to see some arbitrary values of the grouped data, but you really need to understand that it's happening when you view your results

Comment: @fyrye The purpose of this query is to just make a listing that does not repeat these records with 2h interval, no matter how much the value comes in the columns, you see? After that, as the ids are coming too, while selecting the line, the users are redirected to another screen where I deal with separate record as I have the ids of both

Comment: @fyrye And also the maximum that will repeat is 3 records, there is the possibility of repeating more than this in that interval of 2 hours, understand?

Comment: All the same, you might want to consider replacing `*` with `inclusao_oco, sinistro, prefixo, data, DATE(horaIfull_oco)` (the grouped columns) - this way the application will be more portable if you should ever need to run it on a server with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode turned on.  Just a thought...

Comment: @billynoah Thank you, I will evaluate the doing, good practices are always welcome, mainly coming from people with a level higher than mine

Comment: @WotonSampaio I am just cautioning you that your "listing" of values within each of the columns, will be subject to random values within the 2 hour groupings, unless you use an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) on the columns you use. Since `GROUP BY` does not just truncate the records in the same way every time otherwise.

Comment: @billynoah After some tests, I realized that your solution does not work exactly :/, Imagine there are 2 records, one with 9h and another with 10, int (9/2) = 4 and int (10/2) = 5, values ​​do not beat

Comment: Remembering that the interválo of hours should be 2h up and 2h down

Comment: Perhaps there is a language barrier here and I am not understanding your requirements, but to the best of my knowledge the query I provided works to "*do a group by that has a range of 2 hours*" – which is how you phrased your question.  Bear in mind - as has been discussed multiple times in comments, that you can possibly have many rows on consecutive minutes.  This means that you simply have to draw the line somewhere arbitrary, which is what my answer (and @Rick James above) both do in slightly different ways.

Comment: At this point you've got two good answers from high rep users - if something's still wrong perhaps you are either (a) not explaining yourself clearly, or (b) not grasping the complexities of your own problem enough to understand the approaches that have been suggested.  In any event **unaccepting** my answer two days after you proclaimed "*Dude, you saved my freelancer, thank you*" is definitely not incentive for me to work harder at getting you an answer you are happy with.

Answer (score 1):

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(horaIfull_oco) / 7200)
```

(`7200` is 2 hours.)

If you want to get the base time for each group:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(
   FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(horaIfull_oco) / 7200)
              , 7200)
```

This technique can be adapted to any regular time interval by changing `7200`.

Comment: Considering that you have 2 records, one from `2018-11-19 23:50:00` and one from `2018-11-20 00:10:00` they do not join with your query, so far the only query I saw that really solved my problem is the one I answered below

Comment: @WotonSampaio - that is a much tougher problem.  What if there is a reading every 119 minutes.  Each consecutive pair _could_ be combined, but which pairs _should_ be combined.  Or every 11 minutes.  I suggest that even 2-hour boundaries is as good as any other algorithm.

Comment: I do not understand very well what I mean (my English is a bit bad), and I also do not know much about database optimization, if you can leave a better explanation I thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a database table having a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    c1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c2 VARCHAR(100),
    c3 VARCHAR(100),
    c4 DATE,
    c5 TIME,
    c6 DATETIME);

INSERT INTO t1 (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) 
VALUES 
(1,'DDA1123_12112018','55307','2018-12-11','00:43:00', '2018-12-11 00:43:00'),
(2,'DDA1123_12112018','55307','2018-12-11','00:07:00', '2018-12-11 00:07:00'),
(3,'DDA1124_12112018','55308','2018-12-11','03:07:00', '2018-12-11 03:07:00'),
(4,'DDA1124_12112018','55308','2018-12-11','04:07:00', '2018-12-11 04:07:00'),
(5,'DDA1124_12112018','55308','2018-12-11','07:07:00', '2018-12-11 07:07:00'),
(6,'DDA1125_12112018','55309','2018-12-11','06:07:00', '2018-12-11 06:07:00'),
(7,'DDA1125_12112018','55309','2018-12-11','07:57:00', '2018-12-11 07:57:00'),
(8,'DDA1126_12112018','55310','2018-12-11','08:07:00', '2018-12-11 08:07:00'),
(9,'DDA1127_12112018','55311','2018-12-11','12:07:00', '2018-12-11 12:07:00'),
(10,'DDA1127_12112018','55311','2018-12-11','14:07:00', '2018-12-11 14:07:00'),
(11,'DDA1127_12112018','55311','2018-12-11','17:07:00', '2018-12-11 17:07:00');
```

In that case you could use `CASE ... WHEN` in `GROUP BY` like in this example query.

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,
CASE TRUE
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 0 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 2 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 4 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN 6
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 8 AND 10 THEN 8
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 10
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 12 AND 14 THEN 12
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 14 AND 16 THEN 14
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 16 AND 18 THEN 16
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 THEN 18
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 20 AND 22 THEN 20
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 22 AND 24 THEN 22
END AS c7 FROM t1
GROUP BY c7;
```

You can view the results of the above example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef2361/2).

**EDIT**

For better results the above query could be re-written:

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,
CASE TRUE
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 1 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 0 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 2 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 4 AND 5 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 4 
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 6
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 8
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 10 AND 11 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 10
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 12 AND 13 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 12
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 14 AND 15 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 14
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 16 AND 17 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 16
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 18 AND 19 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 18
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 20 AND 21 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 20
WHEN HOUR(c6) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 AND MINUTE(c6) BETWEEN 0 AND 59 THEN 22
END AS c7 FROM t1
GROUP BY c7;
```

You can view the results of the edited example in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef2361/4).